# Using AJAX with CActiveForm and my custom HTML code

Tags: forms, yii

I am trying to make Yii forms for my project.

On one page it should be both a CActiveForm and my own custom HTML code with my controls which is validated and submitted using my custom JavaScript.

The form is to be submitted through AJAX, because otherwise I would need to remember and restore the values of my controls (otherwise the user input would be lost on unsuccessful submit), what I don't want to do. So AJAX.

What are the correct CActiveForm options to check the active form validity, call my own validation code, and submitting only if all is valid?

Insofar, I've written this code:

```
  <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'contract-update-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('onsubmit'=>'return on_submit();'),
  )); ?>
```

But it calls my validation twice what causes alert() with my error message twice. Why? And how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `afterValidate` option :

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'contract-update-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'afterValidate'=>'js:on_submit',
    ),
)); ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#clientOptions-detail